# MAMP local host not working

Tags: localhost, osx-mountain-lion, mamp

My MacBook Pro 13 inch is running on OS X 10.8.2 and I have downloaded MAMP 2.1.4.

I want to run the MAMP program. After I connect to the servers successfully I then try to press the 'open start page'. It takes me to the Google Chrome browser with a page that says the page can't be found.

I've installed MAMP and am running the Apache server and MySQL servers fine through either port 80 and 3306 or 8888 and 8889 - using either combination makes the status lights go green. The local host can't be found for some reason.

I have done extensive research where I have:

- uninstalled and reinstalled MAMP three times and restarted the computer each time
- physically put in the address to the start page, ie `http://<localhost>:8888/`. This is what it says when I put that in the address bar: *Oops! Google Chrome could not find localhost:8888* or the same for `http://localhost:80/`
- made sure in the MAMP preferences under PHP, that PHP5 is enabled and then stopped and started MAMP again (i have 5.4.10 php version and Chache is XChache)
- tried to use sharing under system preferences to enable internet sharing - does nothing.

What should I do?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue i just changed the port for apache to 90 and connected then to 
http://localhost:90

127.0.0.1:90

respectively.
Fixed it in my case.
Hope that helps.

---

System 
iMac
OS X Yosemite 10.10.1
MAMP 3.0.7.3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my Macbook Pro 15 inch running OS X 10.8.3.

I could access my wordpress development environment (MAMP 2.1.3) when disconnected from a network but if I connected to my wireless network or the internet via my HTC One XL i could no longer access localhost.

I removed my manually configured DNS settings for my wireless connection and happy days.. I could connect to my development environment using both Localhost and `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Check MAMP>> preferences >> ports >> set MAMP ports to default

that will change ports to the following :

`Apache >> 8888 Ngnix >> 7888 MySql >> 8889`

Then (after pasting wordpress folder in the C:\MAMP\htdocs )it will work when you use http://localhost:8888/wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, my hack was pretty basic: I rebooted my system and it worked. There is a chance that you have multiple instances of Apache running which is blocking the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to have the wordpress folder in the right place after you download it! 
Should be: `Macintosh HD> Applications> MAMP> htdocs> wordpress`

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I had this same issue and was missing the following from my `/etc/hosts` file. I had to sudo edit this file, add these values (I added them at the top), save and restart MAMP.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue in windows and observed MYSQL is working and Apache was not working. Then I change PHP version from MAMP-->Preference-->PHP. And Restart the server also. Then it start working. Hope it will help you also.

Note: If you using any other Apache application at 80 port then change for MAMP apache to 81 or 90 from Preference.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and restarting the Apache servers got it resolved.